# Accuracy in Calculating Fourth Derivative using Finite Differences in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am writing a small code to calculate the fourth derivative using the method of finite differences in tensorflow. This is as follows:

```
def action(y,x):
    #spacing between points.
    h = (x[-1] - x[0]) / (int(x.shape[0]) - 1)
    
    #fourth derivative 
    dy4 = (y[4:] - 4*y[3:-1] + 6*y[2:-2] - 4*y[1:-3] + y[:-4])/(h*h*h*h)

    return dy4

x = tf.linspace(0.0, 30, 1000)
y = tf.tanh(x)
dy4 = action(y,x)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
plt.plot(sess.run(dy4))
```

This results in the following graph:

[image: Graph]

However if I use essentially the same code but just using numpy, the results are much cleaner:

```
def fourth_deriv(y, x):
    h = (x[-1] - x[0]) / (int(x.shape[0]) - 1)
    dy = (y[4:] - 4*y[3:-1] + 6*y[2:-2] - 4*y[1:-3] + y[:-4])/(h*h*h*h)
    return dy

x = np.linspace(0.0, 30, 1000)
test = fourth_deriv(np.tanh(x), x)
plt.plot(test)
```

Which gives:

[image]

What is the issue here? I was thinking at first that the separation between points could be too small to give an accurate computation, but clearly, that's not the case if numpy can handle it fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is related to the choice of floating-point types.

- `tf.linspace` automatically selects `tf.float32` as its type, while
- `np.linspace` creates a `float64` array, which has much more precision.

Making the following modification:

```
start = tf.constant(0.0, dtype = tf.float64)
end = tf.constant(30.0, dtype = tf.float64)
x = tf.linspace(start, end, 1000)
```

causes a smooth plot to appear:
[image]

It's worth noting further that Tensorflow does include an automatic differentiation, which is crucial for machine learning training and is hence well-tested - you can use gradient tapes to access it and evaluate a fourth derivative without the imprecision of numeric differentiation using finite differences:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess2:
  x = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(0, 30, 1000))
  sess2.run(tf.compat.v1.initialize_all_variables())
  with tf.GradientTape() as t4:
    with tf.GradientTape() as t3:
      with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
        with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
          y = tf.tanh(x)

        der1 = t1.gradient(y, x)
      der2 = t2.gradient(der1, x)
    der3 = t3.gradient(der2, x)
  der4 = t4.gradient(der3, x)
  print(der4)

  plt.plot(sess2.run(der4))
```

The accuracy of this method is far better than can be achieved using finite difference methods. The following code compares the accuracy of auto diff with the accuracy of the finite difference method:

```
x = np.linspace(0.0, 30, 1000)
sech = 1/np.cosh(x)
theoretical = 16*np.tanh(x) * np.power(sech, 4) - 8*np.power(np.tanh(x), 3)*np.power(sech,2)

finite_diff_err = theoretical[2:-2] - from_finite_diff
autodiff_err = theoretical[2:-2] - from_autodiff[2:-2]

print('Max err with autodiff: %s' % np.max(np.abs(autodiff_err)))
print('Max err with finite difference: %s' % np.max(np.abs(finite_diff_err)))

line, = plt.plot(np.log10(np.abs(autodiff_err)))
line.set_label('Autodiff log error')
line2, = plt.plot(np.log10(np.abs(finite_diff_err)))
line2.set_label('Finite difference log error')
plt.legend()
```

and yields the following output:

```
Max err with autodiff: 3.1086244689504383e-15
Max err with a finite difference: 0.007830900165363808
```

and the following plot (the two lines overlap after around 600 on the X-axis):
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! The note on tensorflow's gradients is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually one more question if it's okay. Is there a functionality to do an integral in tensorflow? As in where you input an array of x values and y values and it returns the integral?

Comment: @Tabin I don't believe there is, but I could be mistaken. My understanding is that symbolic and semi-symbolic (similar to autodiff) mechanisms are straightforward and always-solvable for differentiation, but very arcane and not always solvable in closed-form for integration. (https://xkcd.com/2117/ is a relevant comedic take on this). https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109907/31402 seems to confirm that such an algorithm is not widely known.

Comment: @Tabin "functionality to do an integral" No.  The reason why is because arbitrary compositions of functions can be differentiated using the chain rule.  So in tensorflow, if each function knows its derivative, then any combination of functions can compute its derivative numerically easily.  No such analogue exists for integrating compositions of functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the default precision in Tensorflow is **32** bits, but the default precision in numpy is **64** bits. A simple solution is to replace your linspace as follows:

```
x = tf.linspace(tf.constant(0.0, dtype='float64'), 
                tf.constant(30, dtype='float64'), 1000)
```